# Need an upright-style serif math font

Tags: math-mode, fontspec, unicode-math

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}[
    UprightFont     =Source Sans Pro-Light,
    BoldFont        =Source Sans Pro-Semibold,
    ItalicFont      =Source Sans Pro-Light Italic,
    BoldItalicFont  =Source Sans Pro-Semibold Italic]
\begin{document}
Maths Formula: $F=ma$

I cannot get upright serif when I use "mathrm" command: $\mathrm{F=ma}$
\end{document}
```

I have changed my fonts by using fontspec package. When I type in math mode, I want the font to be upright serif. However, the font in math mode is serif but becomes the font I set when I add \mathrm. How can I get an upright serif font in math mode?

Comment: You have to load a matching math font, but remember: There is a reason for those letters to be italic. There is also a reason when a letter is upright, or bold, or blackletter, or script ... There is a meaning behind it.

Comment: Aside: If you load the `fontspec` package, you should almost certainly *not* be using the `inputenc` package as well.

Comment: unrelated but do not use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (it does nothing  other than issue a warning saying it should not be used with xetex/luatex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Remark: I updated this answer significantly after the OP clarified his/her objectives.)

I suggest you (a) load the `unicode-math` package and (b) specify the option `math-style=upright` when running `\setmathfont`. You didn't specify *which* serif math font family you wish to use; I'm assuming it's `Latin Modern Math`.

Aside: Since you're loading the `fontspec` package, you shouldn't be loading the `inputenc` package with the option `utf8`.

[image]

Do not use `\mathrm`, as that'll give you letters that use the *text* font -- which you've defined to be a sans-serif font.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % don't load this package!
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % <-- new
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}[
    UprightFont    = *-Light,
    ItalicFont     = *-Light Italic,
    BoldFont       = *-Semibold,
    BoldItalicFont = *-Semibold Italic]

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[math-style=upright] % <-- new
\begin{document}
Maths Formula: $F=ma$
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I want the font to be serif upright, not to be the text font. The screenshot is used to say that I cannot get serif upright when  I use \mathrm.

Comment: I am sorry about misleading you. Sorry.

Comment: @Superfrankie - I've updated my answer significantly.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. But in my document, why "font-not-found" error appears for Latin Modern Math?

Comment: @Superfrankie - Which TeX distribution is installed on your system? and, do you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? (I use LuaLaTeX.)

Comment: I changed from XeLaTex to LuaLaTex. It works. Thank you.

Comment: @Superfrankie -- Assuming that the Latin Modern Math font was installed properly, XeLaTeX should be able to locate it if one specifies the "raw" file name in the argument of `\setmathfont`. E.g., `\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[<further options>]`.

Comment: @Superfrankie are you on Mac OS X? then there is a trick to get XeTeX find the MacTeX/TeXLive provided fonts. Out of the box you need to use filenames as pointed out by Mico's comment.

Comment: +1, great answer. Also some good comments on packages, but one or two more observations. You drop `amsfonts` without comment, as it’s also obsoleted by `fontspec` or `unicode-math`. But if you need any of the fonts in the package, there are free replacements. Neo Euler is the only new font you would need to download to get essentially everything in `amsfonts`, in OpenType. Also, of you’re loading `unicode-math`, you probably do not need to load `amssymb` as well. All or nearly all its glyphs are in Unicode and declared with the same names in `unicode-math`.

Comment: Finally, `mathtools` is available as an update to `amsmath`.

Comment: @Davislor: The reason I don't load `amsfonts` explicitly is purely because it's loaded automatically if the `amssymb` package is loaded. No other reason. For sure, the `amsfonts` package is not "obsoleted" if `fontspec` and/or `unicode-math` are loaded.

Comment: @Mico Fair enough. The OP knows which parts of the package she(?) is using in the document.  I’d try taking `amsfonts` and `amssymb` out and seeing if it still works. Or check here to see if those symbols are already in `unicode-math`: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf

Comment: @Davislor - I don't think it's quite right to call `mathtools` an "update" to `amsmath`. For sure, `mathtools` loads `amsmath` automatically, and `mathtools` does modify a couple of settings implemented by `amsmath`. I'm not sure that this should be called an `update`. A part of the `mathtools` package does build on and extend the capabilities of the `amsmath` package, e.g., by providing environments called `multlined` and `dcases`. Other parts of `mathtools`, though, add genuinely new capabilities that have no discernible connection to what's happening in `amsmath`.

Comment: @Mico An “extension,” perhaps? In any case, it’s a package one can load instead. Authors can check out the documentation and see if they want to consider using it.

Answer (score 3):

The end result makes me weep.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathastext}

\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}[
  UprightFont    = *-Light,
  BoldFont       = *-Semibold,
  ItalicFont     = *-Light Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-Semibold Italic
]

\begin{document}

Maths Formula: $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}$
\[
\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 = n\Bigl(n+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)(n+1)
\quad\text{for every $n$}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This code generates the following warning message: "Package mathastext Warning: Unknown option 'upright'." I think the key pointer for the OP (and future readers of this posting) should be that one must load the `mathastext` message *before* running `\setmainfont` in order to get uprignt/serif math glyphs.

Comment: is your weeping due to the fact the math formula is mssing a /3 ? ;-)

Comment: @jfbu No, wrong fonts call for wrong math. `;-)`

Comment: Good point, but as there is a doubt whether all of that was intentional, I propose a substantial transfer of reps to my account ``:)``. This will perturbate the 654321 speculations and ruin all those who bet money on this, but that's allright to me.

Answer (score 1):

This was originally a comment to @egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423076/4686). But now I have added a few extras. I am using `Source Serif Pro` which apparently has no italic variant.

In particular, `fontspec` should be loaded with `no-math` option when using `mathastext`.

Besides, I did not quite understand if the OP wants *all* letters in math to be upright, or only for `\mathrm` etc.. to produce serif letters.

I sort of expect OP's wanted letters italic, except when using `\mathrm` but well here we go. Anyway Source Serif Pro in TeXLive appears to have no italic variant, so this anyhow clinches the discussion here about whether letters should be italic or upright in math:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}[
  UprightFont    = *-Light,
  BoldFont       = *-Semibold,
]

\usepackage[defaultmathsizes, basic]{mathastext}

\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}[
  UprightFont    = *-Light,
  BoldFont       = *-Semibold,
  ItalicFont     = *-Light Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-Semibold Italic
]

\begin{document}

Physics Formula: $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}$.

Wrong Maths Formula:
\[
\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 = n\Bigl(n+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)(n+1)
\quad\text{for every $n$}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(the above is wrong math formula, see next).

---

By the way, I enjoy aesthetically serif in text and sans in math. This can be achieved here this way:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}[
  UprightFont    = *-Light,
  BoldFont       = *-Semibold,
]

\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro}[
  UprightFont    = *-Light,
  BoldFont       = *-Semibold,
  ItalicFont     = *-Light Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-Semibold Italic
]

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes, basic]{mathastext}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}


\begin{document}

Maths Formula: $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}$
\[
\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 = \frac{n\Bigl(n+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)(n+1)}3
\quad\text{for every $n$}
\]

\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico I find as a rule that the exact opposite setting: serif letters in text, sans letters in math, gives pleasing aesthetic results. Here I am to my dismay almost thinking like egreg that this is a bit painful on the eyes...

Comment: +1 for actively imagining that by the locution "upright serif", the OP might have been thinking of employing serif font (such as `Source Serif Pro`) which harmonizes with `Source Sans Pro`. In my answer, I had assumed (quite possibly invalidly...) that the term "upright serif" meant the system default, viz., Latin Modern (Roman)...

Comment: @Mico, I have read again OP's and can't conclude about what is asked really. Thus I decided to educate the public and use serif in text and sans in math mode ...